# let $g:X \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be $\sigma$-integrable. If $|\int g \, d\sigma| = \int|g| d\, \sigma$, then $g \geq 0$ a.e. or $g \leq 0$ a.e.

Tags: measure-theory

**Proposition.**

Let $g:X \to \overline{\mathbb{R}}$ be $\sigma$-integrable. If $|\int g \, d\sigma| = \int|g| d\, \sigma$, then $g \geq 0$ a.e. or $g \leq 0$ a.e.

**Proof**

Suppose that $|\int g \, d\sigma| = \int|g| d\, \sigma$ and $g \not\leq 0$ almost everywhere. Then we know that $\sigma([g> 0])$ has positive measure. We need to show that $g \geq 0$ almost everywhere, that is, $\sigma([g<0]) = 0$.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: GEdgar, Sorry - those were typos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, by replacing $g$ with $-g$, we may assume that 
$$
\int_X g\,\mathrm{d}\sigma \geq 0.
$$
Then, 
we must have
\begin{align*}
\int_X g_+\,\mathrm{d}\sigma - \int_X g_-\,\mathrm{d}\sigma = \int_X g\,\mathrm{d}\sigma = \left\vert \int_X g\,\mathrm{d}\sigma \right\vert &= \int_X |g|\,\mathrm{d}\sigma\\
&= \int_X (g_+ +  g_{-})\,\mathrm{d}\sigma\\
&= \int_X g_+\,\mathrm{d}\sigma + \int_X g_-\,\mathrm{d}\sigma.
\end{align*}
However, this would imply that
$$
0 = 2 \int_X g_-\,\mathrm{d}\sigma
$$
whence it follows that $g_- = 0$ almost everywhere. From here, we can infer that $g \geq 0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: I'm confused about this step: $$\int_{X+} |g|\,\mathrm{d}\sigma + \int_{X-} |g|\,\mathrm{d}\sigma \\
= \int_{X_+} g\,\mathrm{d}\sigma - \int_{X_-} g\,\mathrm{d}x\\$$

Comment: @johnnyboy23 If $x \in X_{+}$ then $g(x) > 0$ and if $x \in X_-$ then $g(x) < 0$. Consequently, we have $|g(x)| = g(x)$ and $|g(x)| = -g(x)$ respectively.

Comment: Got it. Thanks.